# Как отловить ошибку в Laravel и отправить ее на почту, кроме

Tags: laravel

Как отловить ошибки в laravel и отправить ее на почту, исключая 404 ошибку

Чтобы отправить все ошибки я добавил метод `report` в фаил - app/Exceptions/Handler.php
В нем я собираю нужную информацию и отправляю на почту

```
public function report(Throwable $e) {
    $data = [
        'description' => $e->getMessage(),
        'file' => $e->getFile(),
        'line' => $e->getLine()
    ];
    SendMailReport::dispatch($data );
}
```

Письмо с ошибками приходит на почту, но есть проблема, он так же отправляет письмо, если открывается несуществующая страница и код ответа у страницы 404 -

```
Описание:  
Файл: /www/site.ru/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
Строка: 1119
```

Как исключить отправку ошибку письма для 404 ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел в вопросе - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297586/how-do-i-get-the-http-status-code-from-an-exception-thrown-in-laravel

```
if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface) {
    $status = $exception->getStatusCode();
}
```